# Magento Cart Same product adding in different lines

Tags: magento

While adding same product to cart, it's adding in new line but it needs to update the qty, if the same product id already in cart.

I need it in same line with qty update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php` class. `representProduct`  method is responsible for new row or line. To add same product multiple time you have to return false every time.

I have assumed the you have overried this class successfully.

```
/**
   * Check product representation in item
   *
   * @param   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
   * @return  bool
   */
  public function representProduct($product)
  {
   return false;
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to hook  **catalog_product_load_after**  and add below code in observer.php.

```
public function addPostData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

$action = Mage::app() -> getFrontController() -> getAction();

if ($action -> getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {

    if ($action -> getRequest() -> getParam('seller')) {

        $item = $observer -> getProduct();

        $additionalOptions = array();

        /// Add here your additional data
        $additionalOptions[] = array('label' => 'Seller', 'value' => "seller 1");

        $item -> addCustomOption('additional_options', serialize($additionalOptions));
    }
}
}
```

In case you don't have any custom data to apply, Set some random info like **added_at => 4:21 PM, 13 June 2016**

Check this [link](http://www.codepetals.com/add-product-separate-items-shopping-cart/) for more info.

Comment: Your anwser and link are doing the exact opposite of what OP's asking for.